# fasterxml jackson: there is no necessary methods to use @JsonView functionality

Tags: json, jackson, fasterxml

I try to organize dynamic @JsonIgnore property when I convert java-object to json-string. In [example](http://techtraits.com/Programming/2011/08/12/implementing-jackson-views/)
it works in next way
for (codehause jackson)
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
oMapper.**setSerializationConfig**(...

or in [example](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) for fasterxml
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().**setSerializationView**(

**PROBLEM:** bolded method are absent in *my jackson*:

**pom.xml**

```
<jackson.version>2.1.1</jackson.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `ObjectWriter` and `ObjectReader` which do include functionality for setting active view to use. This is different from Jackson 1.x, which exposed them through `SerializationConfig` and `DeserializationConfig`.
You can construct these objects from `ObjectMapper` (mapper.readerXxx() and mapper.writerXxx()); they are reusable, and offer more thread-safe configurability than `ObjectMapper`.